# Android app UI - PSD, what next?

Tags: android, user-interface, psd

I'm designing the UI for an Android application. I have the layered PSD ready now, but I'm not sure whats the next step. For the web, I would just slice the images and write html/CSS manually.

Thanks

Comment: ... sounds like web-app and not a native app. Follow best practices for web based app then and use an emulator for preview/testing I guess

Comment: No, not a web-app, its a native app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use slices at all, just save the layers (background, buttons, etc.) out as individual PNGs, and set them up in a XML layout. I hope you don't have your layout sized for an exact resolution; keep in mind there are many different screen resolutions you have to support.

Comment: just to add, if you want a flexible layout with minimal work, then you should design your UI so you can use Nine-Patch technique http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Comment: This is good advice too. Nine patch images are really cool to use in some instances, for sure.